# Integer ArrayList not appending values but replacing them

Tags: android, arrays, list, listview, arraylist

So I have a listview which when you click on an individual row it starts a new activity. In the new activity there is a checkbox that when checked puts a checkmark next to the listview row that was initially clicked. I'm using an integer array lists to store the positions of the listview rows that should have check marks next to them.

What's happening is the values I'm trying to add to the ArrayList are just replacing the previous value instead of appending it to the end.

here's my getView method in my adapter where I'm trying to do this

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater routeInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = convertView;
        if(customView == null){customView = routeInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);}

        CharSequence singleRoute = getItem(position);
        TextView routeText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.routeText);
        routeText.setText(singleRoute);

       ///check mark imageview///
        ImageView checkImageView = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.checkImageView);

    ///image id for checkmark
        int checkImageResourceId = ((Activity) getContext()).getIntent().getIntExtra("checkImageResource",0);

    ///listview item position added to list array    
    int listViewItemPosition = ((Activity) getContext()).getIntent().getIntExtra("listViewItemPosition",0);

        ////list where I want to store equivalent checked routes////////

        List<Integer> checkedRoutePosition = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        checkedRoutePosition.add(listViewItemPosition);

  for(int i=0; i<checkedRoutePosition.size(); i++)
    if(position  ==     checkedRoutePosition.get(i)) {
         checkImageView.setImageResource(checkImageResourceId);
       }
        return customView;
```

thank you for any input!

Comment: Would it be possible for you to wrap this in an object? So store the relevant value on your `CheckedRoute` object and then deal with a single array of `CheckedRoute` objects with a `shouldShowCheckbox` boolean value on it? It would simplify things for you and you wouldnt have to worry about things getting out of sync if you edit the array or want to reorder your list.

Comment: I'm not really sure honestly I'm really new to programming and would have no idea how to accomplish that. This seemed the most straight forward but I'm probably mistaken.

Comment: You might be want to take a look at SparseBooleanArray instead https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html

Answer (score 0):

As Nic Robertson said that create Bean class for Route

```
public class Route{
int a,b;

public void set(int x,int y){
    a=x;
    b=y;
}

public boolean isChecked(){
    return a==b;
}
}
```

create an **ArrayList**

update getView() base on the arrayList

Comment: How would I update get view based on the array list? Sorry I'm just really new to this.

Answer (score 0):

replace your code:

```
if( each checkedRoutes position in array == each checkedRoutePosition in array){
    checkImageView.setImageResource(checkImageResourceId);
}
```

with:

```
boolean state = false;
if(checkedRoutes.size() == checkedRoutePosition.size()) {
  state = true;
  for(int i=0; i<checkedRoutes.size(); i++)
    if(checkedRoutes.get(i) != checkedRoutePosition.get(i)) {
      state = false;
      break;
    }
}
if(state)
  checkImageView.setImageResource(checkImageResourceId);
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try this later today and let you know how it works.

Comment: So I tried this code but its only allowing me to set the checkmark at one row of the listview at a time. If I check off 2 rows only the most recently checked off row shows the checkmark. Like it takes the checkmark off the first row and puts it on the next row I check. I want checks to be able to be shown on multiple rows.

Comment: Im thinking maybe the values in the array list get replaced instead of keeping them and adding the values for the second row that needs to be checked.